# Center of gravity of optical flow cluster

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I need to find the center of gravity of the optical flow vectors. I applied the OpenCV Lucas Kanade function and can visually see the optical flow vectors. Now how do I cluster these vectors and find their center of gravity? Finding the location where the flow vectors are clustered is what I want to achieve.

I get the vectors are Point2f previous points and next points. I am not sure how to cluster these vectors. If I use **kmeans** function, then what should be the structure of the Mat **samples**?

kmeans(**samples**, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 0.0001, 10000), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what results you want to achive. If you want to cluster same moving pixels than you should compute the motion by estimating the difference between the next and previous points the code would look like follows:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> prevPts, currPts;
... run lucas kanade ...
cv::Mat samples(prevPts.size(), 2, CV_32FC1);
for(unsigned int n = 0; n < prevPts.size(); n++)
{
  samples.at<float>(n,0) = currPts[n].x - prevPts[n].x;
  samples.at<float>(n,1) = currPts[n].y - prevPts[n].y;
}
... run clustering
```

this like a global approach. But in most cases you also need to the position into account. Than you have to consider other segmentation methods or you have to add the position as additional dimensions.